# Should return float number but it returns " - " how can i solve this?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
user_agent_desktop = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '\
  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 '\
  'Safari/537.36'

headers = { 'User-Agent': user_agent_desktop}

hisse="ACSEL"

url= "https://www.halkyatirim.com.tr/skorkart/"+str(hisse)+"?HisseKod="+str(hisse)+"&Tarih=2021-03-07"
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  # Send request

code = resp.status_code  # HTTP response code
if code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')  # Parsing the HTML
   
else:
    print(f'Error to load : {code}')
    
st1 = soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"container-fluid"})
st2 = st1.find("main",attrs={"class":"col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4"})
st3 = st2.find("div",attrs={"class":"container skor-container"})
nkbo= st3.find("p",attrs={"id":"mNKBO"}).text
print(nkbo)
```

`nkbo` should return a float number but it returns `" - "`.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: hisse is already a string. It does not need to be cast as string. The page appears to be largely dynamic. Have you checked the data you want is in the page source? Otherwise, check network tab, of browser, for other requests returning your desired content.

Comment: I see it from a post request to https://www.halkyatirim.com.tr/Servis/FinnetService?Metod=null The payload is `{"Param":"{\"RaporParams\":{\"Url\":\"cms-halkyatirim-finansaltablolar-revize-finansallar-degisimler-revizeson\",\"RaporParametreleri\":[{\"key\":\"Kod\",\"value\":\"ACSEL\"},{\"key\":\"HesapDonem\",\"value\":\"2020/12\"}]}}","ServisUrl":"RaporTabloHesapla"}` there are loads of answers on Stackoverflow showing how to find these requests in network tab.

Comment: More immediately, the bug is that you continue processing after the `else:` as if the request had succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just what's in the html. You might need to check the source because the code is returning what you should expect.

```
nkbo= st3.find("p",attrs={"id":"mNKBO"})
print(nkbo)
<p class="box-price" id="mNKBO">-</p>
```

Comment: thank you for answering but should return like this. 
 <p class="box-price" id="mNKBO">85.19</p>

Comment: Yep, @QHArr figured it out :) That figure is from a post request so it's not directly printed in the html.

Comment: No idea :) I think you should try @QHarr's links above